# How to run git commands in eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse

I am using eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0) and the Git perspective.

I can do a lot of things with  GUI, like pull and push, etc.

but today I am facing an error where a possible solution is to run the  command
`git remote prune origin`

so basically that is the question, do Git perspective in eclipse allows me to enter a command ? particularly that command would be applied to the repository shown in the UI
[image]

I know that I can open a terminal inside eclipse with crtl+alt+shift+t  , but then I need to navigate all the way to the repository.

Comment: For folders and files inside the _Working Tree_ (but not for the _Working Tree_ node) I can right-click and choose _Show In > Terminal_. Alternative, you can use _Copy Path to Clipboard_ (the third last menu item in your screenshot) to copy the directory of the Git repository. Please be aware, that EGit is based on JGit, a Java implementation of Git, and does delegate to the Git command line (git-core). Your Eclipse and EGit/JGit are a couple of releases behind. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can right-click on the repository  and choose Show In > Terminal. Then type in the git command.

Answer (score 0):

One hack would be to,

1. Use the **Copy Path to Clipboard**
2. Open the terminal
3. cd *paste the path(Remove .git from the path)*
4. Execute git command

Comment: When I following your answer I get `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @howlger but I was able to execute a `git pull` command

Comment: _"I can do a lot of things with GUI, like pull and push, etc."_ does not mean the Git command line tool (git-core) is installed. Eclipse does it without it.