# i made github remote repository but i can't commit in remote repository

Tags: git, github

[image]

I clicked add to the index button but didn't work.

About how I made this remote repository:

- There is A user, A repository and B user(me), B repository(remote repository).
- we use A repository as origin repository.
- A push to A repo -> B pull and push to B repo.

It worked so far.

I made clone of B repo in Eclipse and edited some files.
And I tried to put edited files in index.
But the button didn't work like first picture.

How can I commit and push in B repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [Git itself installed](https://git-scm.com/downloads) (in addition of [Eclipse which uses EGit/JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66484366/6309)), you can switch to a command-line and check what is going on:

```bash
cd /path/to/local/repository
git status
git remote -v
```

That way, you can see if:

- a `git remote -v` does display remote repository B URL
- a `git add .` would succeed in adding your file to the index, and switch back to Eclipse to see if it reflects properly the new repository state.

---

The [OP JeonYongWook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19121956/jeonyongwook) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075262/i-made-github-remote-repository-but-i-cant-commit-in-remote-repository/73075469#comment129064037_73075469):

> It is solved after reboot

This is typical of a process keeping an handle on a file, preventing that file to be accessed by Git (JGit in Eclipse) and put in the index.

A reboot would have killed that process, allowing the files to be freely accessed by Git/JGit, and added to the index.

Comment: @JeonYongWook Sure, but you are supposed to "accept" (green tick) the answer only if you have tried it *and* it has worked ;)

Comment: oops sorry. its solved after reboot. i treid reboot before but i dont know why its solved now

Comment: @JeonYongWook Great, well done. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility, as well as a possible explanation for the root cause of your problem.